# Find sum of elements in an array without using [ or ]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to find the sum of all the elements in an array but nowhere am I allowed to use square brackets([ or ]). I seem to have the logic figured out but can't get it to work. Please tell me where I've gone wrong.
This is the program I wrote

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int i,a,n,sum; 
    int *ptr; 
    ptr=&a; 
    printf("Enter the number of elements in an array\n"); 
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    printf("Enter the array elements\n"); 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
    { 
        scanf("%d",ptr+sizeof(int)*i); 
    } 
    sum=0; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
    { 
    sum=sum+*(ptr+sizeof(int)*k); 
    } 
    printf("The sum of the elements in the array is %d",sum); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",ptr+sizeof(int)*i);` => `scanf("%d", ptr + i);` `sum=sum+*(ptr+sizeof(int)*k);` => `sum = sum + *(ptr + i);`, `a` is not an array you shoud declare `a` after your first `scanf()`, `int a[n];`

Comment: You didn't allocate for ptr. You just make it point to an integer. Therefore, in the loop, it will point to incorrect location after the first iteration.

Comment: Stargateur That was the first thing I tried. But if I do that, it doesn't accept all the input. If I enter 5 as the number of elements, It only takes 2 inputs

Comment: Take advantage of variable length array (VLA) (i.e. C99 feature) and notice that `a[i] same *(a+i)`.

Comment: CroCo I believe that method requires me to declare and array in the start as int a[10], but that can't be done as [ and ] are forbidden characters

Comment: Ozgur can you perhaps show me how it should be done? Because I'm not allowed to include anything either and malloc.h is required for memory allocation

Comment: @Statgateur I'm not allowed to use square brakcets. So doing `int a[n]` isn't possible

Comment: This question, with it's unrealistic constraints, is not useful to future SO users/visitors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unrealistic design constraints are not useful to future SO users/visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you never allocate memory for storing array elements.So

```
int *ptr;//this will be the array
//input n
ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

Now accessing `i`th element of `ptr` is `ptr[i]` which gets resolved to `*(ptr+i)`, so you can replace `ptr[i]` with `*(ptr+i)`

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
{ 
    scanf("%d",&(*(ptr+i)));  //&ptr[i]
}
```

and

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
{ 
sum=sum+ *(ptr+i); //ptr[i]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man. I completely forgot to do that

Answer (score 3):

The pointer-array duality in C is that

```
*(p+i) == p[i]
```

No multiplication by `sizeof` needed in this notation!

Answer (score 2):

You should change your loop like this:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
{ 
    sum=sum+*ptr; 
    ptr++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in this code,
(1) You have not allocated memory for the number of elements you want 
(2) You have allocated memory only for the first element and you have a pointer pointing to that and is incremented. This will cause undefined behaviour
(3) You dont have to say the distance the pointer has to move(ie ptr+ptr+sizeof(int)*i) since it knows it needs to move a distance of sizeof(int) since its an integer pointer

This code inside main should work(sorry I had to write it in C++, please convert the necessary as required),

```
int sum, n; 
printf("Enter the number of elements in an array\n");
cin>> n;
int *ptr = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int)); 
printf("Enter the array elements\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> *ptr++;      
}
ptr--;  //since it would have incremented the last time
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    sum += *ptr--;      
}
printf("The sum of the elements in the array is %d", sum);  
return 0;
```

Thanks!